# Using Apache Velocity for template SQL

Tags: apache, velocity

I want to use Apache Velocity Template Engine to generate SQL query based on the input.
Any sample snippet to get started would be helpful.

```
        JSONObject keysObject = new JSONObject();
        keysObject.put("HistoryId", "1");
        keysObject.put("TenantName", "Tesla");

        Iterator<?> keys = keysObject.keys();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        Map map = new HashMap();

        while( keys.hasNext() ) {
            String key = (String)keys.next();
           map.put(key, keysObject.get(key));
        }
        list.add( map );

        int keyObjectSize = keysObject.length();
```

JSONObject can have more keys, but in this example i am using 2.
I want to use the keys historyId and tenantName to generate below SQL query, Where keys are used as the column name and keys size can be used to generate the value parameter(?1, ?2).

```
INSERT INTO  "Alert" (historyid, tenantname) VALUES (?1, ?2)
```